# Checking contents of cell for contents of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare the contents of pairs of horizontally adjacent cells in excel.

Column A contains text formatted as a list (abc, def, ghi, jkl) and column B contains one of the elements of the list (abc). How would I search the contents of cells in column A for the exact text of cells in column B?

I don't have enough reputation to include an image in my post but I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use something like `=FIND(CONCAT(",",B1,","),CONCAT(",",A1,","))` You need to add the comma's around A and B, since the element might be first or last in the list, and you want an exact match. Things would be a lot easier if the list would be a normal Excel range instead of a comma separated list: `=VLOOKUP(B1,A1:A5,1,FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you! could you expand on what the functions do? that way I could modify the code if I needed to

Comment: Google is your friend: FIND tries to find a text in a larger text, CONCAT is used to concatenate strings. If column A contains `abc,def,ghi,jkl` then the CONCAT will result in `,abc,def,ghi,jkl,`. Same for column B: assuming that contains `def` then the CONCAT returns `,def,`. Finding `,def,` in `,abc,def,ghi,jkl,` returns the position of the string, or `#VALUE!` when not found

Comment: In `C1` try: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0)),"No","Yes")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[A2] = abc, def, ghi,jkl
[B2] = def

[C2] ="," & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") & ","
[D2] =FIND(TRIM(B2),C2)
[E2] =FIND(TRIM(B2),"," & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") & ",")
[F2] =IFERROR(FIND(TRIM(B2),"," & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") & ","),0)
[Final] =IF(IFERROR(FIND(TRIM(B2),"," & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") & ","),0), "Found", "Not found")
```

In C2 all blanks are removed and a comma added before and after the string. This revised string is tested in D2.
E2 sees the reference to C2 (in D2) replaced with the formula from C2.
F2 embeds the ready formula in an IFERROR function so that it returns 0 if no match is found.

By this method the formula returns either a number, a character position where a match was found) or 0. [Final] embeds the entire formula in an IF statement which converts the result to something you can use.

For testing and studying just copy A2 :F2 from above to a blank worksheet and place the final formula anywhere, perhaps G2. From there it can be copied down as required. C2:F2 are just for explanation and not required for the [Final] to function.

### Edit

The above will find the string "abc" in "abcd". To prevent that please modify the search string as follows.

```
[D2] =FIND("," & TRIM(B2) & ",",C2)
and the final
[Final] =IF(IFERROR(FIND("," & TRIM(B2) & ",","," & SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","") & ","),0), "Found", "Not found")
```

Comment: Only 99% perfectly. I think you will need the modification I have added on. It takes hold when B2 has a string that is a partial of a larger string in A2.